# Adding a new legen in R ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, label

I'm trying to add a new fix line (3.75 in x-axis)that describes the current status and other scenarios that come from a simulation of queues but when I want to add the legend of the fix current status I'm not able to show the legend, for example, I want that it appears a legend called "Current Capacity"

1) Code that runs and shows the line but not the label:

```
p1<-ggplot(Datos, aes(x=Capacity, y=WaitingTime, group=Scenario)) +  geom_line(aes(color=Scenario,linetype=Scenario),size=0.7) +  geom_point(aes(color=Scenario)) +   geom_vline(xintercept = 3.75, linetype="dashed", color = "darkblue", size=1)
```

2) Code that runs and shows the line but not the label:

```
p1<-ggplot(Datos, aes(x=Capacity, x=WaitingTime, group=Scenario)) + geom_line(aes(color=Scenario,linetype=Scenario),size=0.7) + geom_point(aes(color=Scenario)) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3.75, linetype = "Capacity"), show.legend = TRUE) + scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Capacity" = "dashed"))
```

3) Code that runs and shows the labels repeated:

```
p1<-ggplot(Datos, aes(x=Capacity, x=WaitingTime, group=Scenario)) + geom_line(aes(color=Scenario,linetype=Scenario),size=0.7) + geom_point(aes(color=Scenario)) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3.75, lty='Capacity'), col = "red")
```

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to map on an aesthetic inside `geom_vline` not used by the other geoms. Using `mtcars` as an example data in the following code I map "Current Capacity" on `alpha` in `geom_vline` . This results in a legend for alpha which then can be adjusted using `scale_alpha_manual` and `guide_legend` to work as a legend for the vertical line.

I borrowed this approach from http://www.quantide.com/ggplot-multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic/.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, group = factor(cyl))) +  
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(cyl)), size = .7) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(gear))) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3.75, alpha = "Current Capacity"), size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Current Capacity" = 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = "dashed", size = 1)))

p1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the qustion from the list of questions still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Sure, I´m new in this, can you explain to me how to mark the question as answered?

Comment: Me too. Just started some weeks ago. And still learning how things work. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for how to mark a question as answered.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to correct my code but i have an error to generate the plot: "Error in factor(Scenario) : object 'Scenario' not found"

Comment: p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=Capacity, y=WaitingTime, group=factor(Scenario))) +  
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(Scenario)), size = .7) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Scenario))) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3.75, alpha = "Current Capacity"), size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Current Capacity" = 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = "dashed", size = 1)))
p1

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Somehow I got not notified about your last comment. In case you haven't solved the problem  yourself: You missed to replace `mtcars` with your dataset, i.e. `Datos`. Should be `p1 <- ggplot(Datos, aes(....` instead of  `p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(....`.